# Python - Extracting error codes from pyodbc

Tags: python, database, error-handling

I am trying to catch the SQL failures when executed with pyodbc. What I would like to get is the error code on the try: / except: but when I purposefully give the truncate table a non-existent table, the script continues on it merrily way. the code I use is listed below. When I pass the correct table name it works as expected.

```
        with pyodbc.connect(connection_string) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                try:
                    cursor.execute(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table}')
                    print(Exception.__name__)
                except pyodbc.Error as ex:
                    error_count += 1
                    sqlstate = ex.args[0]
                    print(sqlstate)
                    send_email(0, "Truncate Table")
                    exit()
```

Comment: If you execute the command outside a `try` block, does it throw any exception? By the way, `print(Exception.__name__)` does not do anything, except printing the name of the class (Exception).

Comment: No, when I run the command outside of the try it just continues as though everything is fine.

Comment: Playing with the code I changed the line from 
cursor.execute(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table}') 
to 
cursor.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE {table}')

And it captured the error correctly, can anyone explain what the f in the parentheses does?

Comment: OK, I have been playing with the code and what I am finding is that without the f in the parenthesis, the table doesn't get truncated but throws an error message if I pass a bogus table name. With an f in the command, the table gets truncated but I cannot trap the error if a bogus table is passed. Any ideas how I can get the this to work as expected?

Comment: You can use `print()` to see the difference. Without the `f`, the engine receives literally `TRUNCATE TABLE {table}`, which is a syntax error. With the `f`, the placeholder will be replaced with the value of the variable `table`. For example, if `table = "test"`, it will run `TRUNCATE TABLE test`.

Comment: @EmilioSilva, thank you for the information. This was the final code that I used and works as expected

try:
    cursor.execute(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table}')
    LOG.info('Truncate %s was successful', table)
except pyodbc.Error as ex:
    LOG.error('Truncate %s failed', table)